# What's the best way to offset an image using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am looking for a way to offset the contents of an OpenCV `Mat`, adding a border colour where there is no image due to the offsetting.

```
void OffsetImage(Mat &image, cv::Scalar bordercolour, int xoffset, int yoffset)
{
    ...
}
```

How can this be done - preferably without copying the input `Mat` image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
void OffsetImage(Mat &image, cv::Scalar bordercolour, int xoffset, int yoffset)
{
    Mat temp(image.rows+2*yoffset,image.cols+2*xoffset,image.type(),bordercolour);
    Mat roi(temp(cvRect(xoffset,yoffset,image.cols,image.rows)));
    image.copyTo(roi);
    image=temp.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most elegant way to do this is by using a perspective transformation:

```
void OffsetImage(cv::Mat &image, cv::Scalar bordercolour, int xoffset, int yoffset)
{
  if(xoffset != 0 && yoffset != 0)
  {
    cv::Mat H = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << 
      1, 0, xoffset, 0, 1, yoffset, 0, 0, 1);

    cv::Mat aux;
    cv::warpPerspective(image, aux, H, image.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR, 
      cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, bordercolour);
    image = aux;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to copy data one way or the other. Once a Mat is created in OpenCV you cannot change the size of it anymore without destroying its contents.

The easiest (and cleanest) way to do this would probably be

```
void OffsetImage(cv::Mat &image, cv::Scalar bordercolour, int xoffset, int yoffset)
{
   cv::Rect upperRect(xoffset, 0, image.cols, yoffset);
   cv::Rect lowerRect(xoffset, image.rows + yoffset, image.cols, yoffset);
   cv::Rect leftRect(0, yoffset, xoffset, image.cols);
   cv::Rect rightRect(image.cols + xoffset, yoffset, xoffset, image.cols);

   cv::Rect upperLeft(0, 0, xoffset, yoffset);
   cv::Rect upperRight(image.cols + xoffset, 0, xoffset, yoffset);
   cv::Rect lowerLeft(0, image.rows + yoffset, xoffset, yoffset);
   cv::Rect lowerRight(image.cols + xoffset, image.rows + yoffset, xoffset, yoffset);

   cv::Mat nimage(image.rows + xoffset*2, image.cols + yoffset*2, image.type());

   nimage(upperRect).setTo(bordercolour);
   nimage(lowerRect).setTo(bordercolour);
   nimage(leftRect).setTo(bordercolour);
   nimage(rightRect).setTo(bordercolour);

   nimage(upperLeft).setTo(bordercolour);
   nimage(lowerLeft).setTo(bordercolour);
   nimage(upperRight).setTo(bordercolour);
   nimage(lowerRight).setTo(bordercolour);

   image.copyTo(nimage(cv::Rect(xoffset, yoffset, image.cols, image.rows)));
   image = nimage;
}
```

OpenCV uses reference counting so the last operation in this listing is extremely cheap.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I did test it and an error came back about accessing pixels outside of a Mat. I'm sure it's very close but I felt setting the background colour was a mildly neater approach to the border. Your reasoning was very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you specify the error more precisely so I can improve the answer? I tested the code on my machine and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation allows the offset to be in ***any*** direction...

```
void OffsetImage(Mat &image, cv::Scalar bordercolour, int xoffset, int yoffset)
{
    Mat offsetImage = Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());
    padded = Mat(image.rows + 2 * abs(yoffset), image.cols + 2 * abs(xoffset), CV_8UC3, bordercolour);
    image.copyTo(padded(Rect(abs(xoffset), abs(yoffset), image.cols, image.rows)));
    image = Mat(padded, Rect(abs(xoffset) + xoffset, abs(yoffset) + yoffset, image.cols, image.rows));

}
```